# How to download the attach files in jira using C#

Tags: c#, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to download the attach files in from jira using the jira techtalk to get the issue and attachments.

```
foreach (var img in issue.fields.attachment)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(img.ToString());

                System.Drawing.Image attachImg = Utilities.DownloadImageFromUrl(item["content"].ToString());
                if (attachImg != null) {
                    var sPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/"), item["filename"].ToString());
                    attachImg.Save(sPath);
                }

            }
```

and in utilities.downloadimagefromurl this is the full code:

```
public static System.Drawing.Image DownloadImageFromUrl(string imageUrl)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image image = null;

        try
        {
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
            webRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
            webRequest.Timeout = 30000;

            System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

            System.IO.Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

            image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

            webResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return image;
    }
```

but gives a null return.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to download the attachment in jira API: I'm using tecktalk Jira Rest Client https://github.com/techtalk/JiraRestClient

Here's the code:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{

    webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(remoteUri + "?&os_username=usernamehere&os_password=passwordhere"), dPath);

}
```

use your jira login username and password.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using `RestSharp`:

```
using RestSharp.Extensions;
```

.

```
Uri uri = new Uri($"http://{jira}/secure/attachment/{attachmentID.ToString()}/" + 
    $"?&os_username={userName}&os_password={password}");

IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(uri, Method.GET);

restClient.DownloadData(request).SaveAs($"{saveLocation}");
```

Answer (score 1):

This really helped me.  My URI was was built as:

```
string uri = string.Format("{0}/secure/attachmentzip/{1}.zip?&os_username={2}&os_password={3}", jira, issue.id, user, password);
```

Comment: `zip` indeed. However, you can also simply add a slash after `{0}/secure/attachment/{1}` and then it's `{0}/secure/attachment/{1}/?&os_username={2}&os_password={3}` and this worked for me. For some reason, instead of querying the ID you query the sub dir and it works fine.